# GitHub Actions can't install R package 'sf' because gdal-config not found or not executable

Tags: r, github-actions, github-pages, gdal, r-sf

I'm using GitHub Actions to automate the updating of a GitHub pages that I host. I used R to create the functionality and produce the R Markdown document that acts as the webpage I'm hosting. Currently my page is dependent upon package 'sf', however I'm running into issues with Actions not being able to download the package 'sf' because of an error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13
configure: CXX: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Users/runner/work/_temp/Library/sf’
```

I'm using macos-lastest, and everything works other than the issue with package 'sf'. Here is the GitHub workflow .yml file that runs this process:

```
name: Updating Citizen Science Report
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is updating the report!
on: push
  #schedule:
    #- cron:  '0 8 * * 1'
    
jobs:
  Update-Citsci-Report-Pages:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Checkout branch into the runner
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2-branch # Set up R
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2 # Set up pandoc for RMD file
          
      - name: Install packages
        run: |
          R -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'
          R -e 'install.packages("lubridate")'
          R -e 'install.packages("kableExtra")'
          R -e 'install.packages("htmltools")'
          R -e 'install.packages("rinat")'
          R -e 'install.packages("rebird")'
          R -e 'install.packages("gt")'
          R -e 'install.packages("sf")'
          
      - name: Run rmd to update info
        run: Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render(input = "index.Rmd")'
      
      - name: Commit files # Commit changes
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git add .
          git diff-index --quiet HEAD || (git commit -m "weekly update of citsci report" && git push)
```

I have tried also installing package 'rgdal' and it seemed to work temporarily. But rerunning today caused the same issue that I thought adding in package 'rgdal' fixed. I think the answer is simply ensuring that the gdal-config file is created successfully, but I haven't been able to accomplish this in the GitHub Actions framework.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: do you absolutely positively require running on macos? Having the action run on windows (where complied binaries are generally available) might sidestep the issue...

Comment: Have you installed an up-to-date version of GDAL? You should of course tell use more complete details of you hardware and software platform.

Comment: Here's what rsbivand wrote to someone back in 2020: "On MacOS, only install CRAN binary packages. If you try to install source, it is your responsibility to install all the external dependencies (not R packages) yourself (and to keep them updated). If you installed the sf you have from the CRAN MacOS repository, all the functions from external libraries were included in a static build, and cannot be used to update just the R package."

Comment: @JindraLacko is probably right: try `ubuntu-latest` instead of `macos-latest`

Comment: I will try that if my current possible solution doesn't work. Right now I've added brew install pkg-config and brew install gdal above the r package install in the workflow. Thanks for everyone's help so far!